# I want to print the output ias weekly salary using the above function, but I am not able to

Tags: c

```
#include\<stdio.h\>
float calculateWeeklySalary(int grade, float hrs_worked)
{
    float ws, hr_rate;
    switch(grade){
        case 1:
            hr_rate = 100.00;
            break;
        case 2:
            hr_rate = 200.00;
            break;
        case 3:
            hr_rate = 300.00;
            break;
        case 4:
            hr_rate = 400.00;
            break;
        case 5:
            hr_rate = 500.00;
            break;              
    }
    ws = hrs_worked \* hr_rate;
    return ws;
}
int main()
{
    int g;
    float hr_work;
    printf("Enter Grade: ");
    scanf("%d", &g);
    printf("Enter Weekly Hours Worked ");
    scanf("%f", &hr_work);
    printf(" The weekly salary: ", calculateWeeklySalary(g,hr_work));
    return 0;   
}
```

I was not able to call the function and display the final output

Comment: What is `\*` in `ws = hrs_worked \* hr_rate;`?

Comment: What is `hr_rate` when `grade < 1 || grade > 5`?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the formatter in the `printf`. It should be:

```c
printf(" The weekly salary: %f", calculateWeeklySalary(g,hr_work));
```

Also: Why are there these Backslashes in your code?

Answer (score 0):

To print your answer which is returned from the function, you can use

```
printf(" The weekly salary: %f", calculateWeeklySalary(g,hr_work));
```

Comment: The comment doesn't add anything new relating to the other answer